# Clusters in nodejs

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing

I am in an internship, and my boss told me to de the next :
Create cluster in nodejs (launch multiple instance of the same file)
Masters shares a DB containing the PID of workers
If a worker don't have a Master it become a Master

I created a cluster in nodejs , i created a DB,I insert update when exit but i don't know how to let Masters communicate, my code:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const cluster = require('cluster');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
const dbParams = {
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'clustersdb',
    password: 'root',
    port: 5433,
};
const pool = new Pool(dbParams);
const workerPool = new Pool(dbParams);
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs - 2; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
    cluster.on('fork', (worker) => {
        insert(worker.process.pid, process.pid)
    });
    
    cluster.on('exit', (worker) => { //for testing : taskkill /F /PID 13112
        update(worker.process.pid)
        cluster.fork();
    });
    cluster.on('message', (worker, message) => {
        console.log('Message from worker' + worker.process.pid + ':' + message);
    });
} else {
    process.send('Hello from worker ' + process.pid);
}
function insert(worker, master) {
    workerPool.query('INSERT INTO worker (worker_id,master_id,status) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)', [worker, master, 'Online'], (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error inserting into database:', err);
        }
    });
}
function update(worker) {
    workerPool.query('UPDATE worker SET status = $1 WHERE worker_id = $2', ['Offline', worker], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error updating database:', err);
        }
    });
}
function fetch(master) {
    workerPool.query('SELECT * FROM worker WHERE master_id = $1', [master], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error fetching from database:', err);
        } else {
            if (result.rows.length > 0) {
                console.log(result.rows);
            } else {
                console.log('No records found in the database for master ' + master);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: "*how to let Masters communicate*" what would be the need for such a communication?

Comment: like if the master1 say to master2 hello those are my workers and the same for the other one